# Sufficient condition for convergence of the sequence $(1/a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I came across a question about convergence of sequences which I found interesting, but I would like comments on whether I have answered it correctly. I shall reproduce the question below.

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. Which of the
>   following conditions is sufficient to ensure that $(1/a_n)$ converges?
>   Give a proof or counter-example as appropriate.
>
> 1. $a_n \to l$ for some $l\in\mathbb{R}$
> 2. $a_n \to l$ for some non-zero
> 3. $(a_n)$ has no convergent subsequence

I think (2) is sufficient since given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n - l| <\epsilon$. Hence $\big|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{l}\big|= \big|\frac{a_n-l}{la_n}\big| <\frac{\epsilon}{|la_n|} <\epsilon$ and so $(1/a_n)$ converges to $\frac{1}{l}$. So this condition is sufficient.

We know (1) is the same as (2) except for the case $l=0$. Let us consider this case. Suppose $a_n\to 0$. If we consider subsequences of $(1/a_n)$ defined by $A_+:=\{a \in a_n : a>0\}$ and $A_-$ defined similarly. If $(1/a_n)$ were convergent, these subsequences ought to both converge to the same limit. However, $A_+ \to \infty$ and $A_-\to -\infty$. Hence $(1/a_n)$ diverges unless $(1/a_n)=A_+$ or $(1/a_n)=A_-$. This condition is not sufficient.

For (3), we note that the fact that $(a_n)$ has no convergent subsequence implies $(a_n)$ is unbounded using the Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem. Does this necessarily imply that $(a_n)$ tends to $\pm \infty$? I think it does and if it does then this would imply $(1/a_n)\to0$ which would make (3) a sufficient condition.

Is my reasoning in each of the 3 cases correct?

Comment: In case (1), since all it's asking for is a counterexample, you can just choose a specific $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n\rightarrow0$ and show that $\{1/a_n\}$ diverges.  There should be some pretty easy examples...

For case (3), 'unbounded' isn't really enough in and of itself; for instance, $\{a_n\}$ where $a_{2n}=1$ and $a_{2n+1}=n$ is unbounded but $\{1/a_n\}$ doesn't converge. You need the slightly stronger condition that you mention, which you should be able to prove...

Comment: (Also, now that I look at it, your reasoning in case (2) is largely correct but one of your inequalities is wrong; if, e.g., $L=\frac14$, then $\frac\epsilon{\left|La_n\right|}\lt\epsilon$ isn't true...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see that for case (1) I could simply cite the sequence $a_n=1/n$. Is the reasoning I gave still correct though? For case (2) how would I fix this proof, any hints? For case (3), could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: For case (2), just use two different epsilons - an $\epsilon$ and a $\zeta$, for instance.  If you're given an $\epsilon$, you can choose an appropriate $\zeta=\zeta(\epsilon)$, use your $N$ such that $n\gt N$ implies $\left|a_n-L\right|\lt \zeta$ and then show that for this $\zeta$, $\left|\frac1a_n-\frac1L\right| \lt\epsilon$.  Plugging through the arithmetic you've done should show what sort of $\zeta$ is good.

Comment: For (3) what I mean is that you're correct that showing that $\{|a_n|\}$ tending to $\infty$ (suitably defined) does imply that $\{|\frac1a_n|\}\to 0$, which in turn implies $\{\frac1a_n\}\to0$.  But unboundedness in and of itself isn't enough to show that $\{|a_n|\}$ tends to infinity (by the example I gave); you'll have to figure out how to show that condition.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry to revive this old question. I had recently thought about a particular aspect of this problem and decided to revisit it. I wanted to clarify your remark about (3). I think knowing that $(a_n)$ contains no convergent subsequence does necessarily imply that $|a_n|\to\infty$, since there can be no divergent but bounded subsequences and therefore all that is left is divergent unbounded sequences. The example you cited: $a_{2n}=1$ and $a_{2n+1}=n$ isn't a counterexample to my claim since it contains a convergent subsequence, namely $a_{2n}\to 1$.

Comment: No worries! That's a good thing to clarify. You're correct that knowing that $\{a_n\}$ doesn't contain a convergent subsequence is enough to imply that $|a_n|\to\infty$. What I was trying to point out in my comment was that the phrasing you used was 'implies that $a_n$ is unbounded [...] does this necessarily imply that $\{a_n\}$ tends to $\pm\infty$?' — and the point I was trying to make was that unboundedness, _in and of itself_ isn't sufficient to imply that $|a_n|\to\infty$; you need more than that.

Comment: But you're correct that (3) _is_ a sufficient condition; just not (quite) through the argument that you initially gave, if that distinction makes sense.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you for coming back to clarify! I see what point you were making now, and the distinction does make sense.